# How to fullfill line of dots

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

please help me with this
How can I fullfill with a line of dots in the blank between food name and price in reactjs?
(Image example)
I’m using Material UI library for my project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVR8y.jpg)

I’m using Material UI library for my project

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
      {coffeeMenu.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={6} key={index}>
          <Link
            underline='none'
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              px: 5,
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: '#000',
              '&:hover': {
                color: '#D8AE78',
                cursor: 'pointer',
              },
            }}
          >
            <Typography>{item.name}</Typography>
            <Typography>{item.price}đ</Typography>
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a div between the food name and price with a dashed border. I would need to see your code to show you exactly how to implement but something like this could work:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.food_name {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.food_price {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.dashed_line {
  flex: 1;
  border-top: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="food_name">Hotdog</p>
  <div class="dashed_line"></div>
  <p class="food_price">$5.99</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i have update my code on top, can MUI library do this ?